# Relatively prime integer

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me to answer the following problem:

Let $F$ a field.

> Show that if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime integer, and $r,s\in F^{\times}$ satisfy $r^m=s^n$ then there are $u,v\in F^{\times}$ such that $r=u^n$ and $s=v^m$.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by relatively prime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ with $an+bm=1$, which is possible because $n$ and $m$ are coprime. Then, $r^{1-an}=r^{bm}=s^{bn}$ so we get $r = s^{bn}r^{an} = (s^br^a)^n$. Similarly, $s^{1-bm}=s^{an}=r^{am}$ so $s=r^{am}s^{bm}=(r^as^b)^m$. Hence, you can pick $u=s^br^a$ and $v=r^as^b$.

Comment: and how to prove that  $u,$ and $v$ are in $F^{\times}$?

Comment: @siwar, they are products of elements in $F^\times$, which is closed under multiplication.

Comment: Huttenhain thanks for your help!

Comment: a last question: are $a,b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$? or in $F$?

Comment: @siwar exactly what I wrote. Observe that picking $a$ and $b$ in $F$ would not necessarily make sense (how to raise and element of $F$ to a "power" which is also an element of $F$?). The fact that these $a$ and $b$ exist follows from the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: thanks again Jesko